# How to use WhereAwait from System.Linq.Async with custom bools

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, blazor, ix.net

I have a database and I make a lot of `Where` calls to it to make a table in Blazor. This takes long because `Where` is not Async. To speed this up I wanted to change the `Where` statements by using: `ToAsyncEnumerable().WhereAwait` from System.Linq.Async.

This is my line of code:

```
series5 = _context.ChickenSeries.ToAsyncEnumerable().WhereAwait(async serie => await ((serie.DatumWeek5 >= firstDay && serie.DatumWeek5 <= lastDay) && serie.SlaughterHouse.SlaughterHouseId != LeegstandID));
```

The error presenting on this line:
*'bool' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' ...*

How do I resolve this issue?

Original post where code is based on:
[How can I use "Where" with an async predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889988/how-can-i-use-where-with-an-async-predicate)
The last answer.

Comment: Why do you need that? And it is wrong that it is slow because `Where is not Async`. It is slow because you put `ToAsyncEnumerable` on top of the table. You have to apply `Where` first. Then `ToListAsync()`

Comment: Actually `async` operations are slower than synchronous versions. But in couple when APP Server is under high load, `async` relaxes server's threads usage.

Comment: For 1 table I have to make +- 100 database calls. This Database is not on the same server, therefore I wanted to make these calls Asyncronous. Would that not make it a lot faster?

Answer (score 0):

`Where` is operator for filtering data and it is DO NOT EXECUTES query, it just defines filter for query. So no `asyncs` is needed for `Where`. You have to apply it on `IQueryable` to filter data.

Try to rewrite your query in the following way:

```cs
var result = await _context.ChickenSeries
    .Where(serie => (serie.DatumWeek5 >= firstDay && serie.DatumWeek5 <= lastDay) && serie.SlaughterHouse.SlaughterHouseId != LeegstandID)
    .ToListAsync();
```

If it is still slow, there are options:

1. Number of returned records is too high
2. Database has no proper indexes and you have to analyze SQL Server execution plan.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if I understand correctly. Where does not make the data transfer smaller? It is a filter used when the data comes back?

Comment: Nope it is used for generating `WHERE` part of the SQL. So data is filtered on the SQL Server side, which makes result returned by server smaller.

Comment: Start from reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/)

Comment: I tried to implement this and I do not get any results back? The line returns nothing, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Probably filter is incorrect.

Comment: When I use Syncronous it works, so don't think so.

Comment: And why is the link I based my code on so different then?

Comment: It should be no differences at all.