# What's the proper way to run an async function in a LINQ where statement?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, async-await, task

What's the correct way to write the following

```
var orders = OrigOrders.Where(async o => await o.Validate(o));
```

I keep getting errors like the following: Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate `function<order, bool>`...

As such I'm writing it like this but this seems superfluous

```
var Orders = new List<Order>();
foreach(var o in OrigOrders)
{
     if (await Validate(o)) orders.Add(co);
}
```

Comment: The [System.Linq.Async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68202534/1892668) nuget  package is probably what you would want to use.